# How can I add new character after each line?

Tags: awk

I am trying to manipulate a file, by adding an `A` after each lines

```
Name
Test
```

However the `awk '{print $0"A"}'  file_list.txt > file_list2.txt` command gives the following result

```
Name
A
Test
A
```

How can I fix it? I want the `A`at the end of the line instead of a new line.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. What version of `awk` and what OS are you using? What's the output of `printf '%s\n%s\n' foo bar | awk '{print $0"A"}'`?

Comment: carriage returns, dos2unix fam

Comment: That returns the expected the output `fooA` `barA`

Comment: @Marco In the following way I can reproduce it `printf '%s\r\n%s\r\n' foo bar | awk '{print $0"A"}'  >test`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few ways to settle this:

1. `sed 's/\r\?$/ A/' file_list.txt`
2. `awk '{print $0"A"}' RS="\r*\n\r*" file_list.txt`
3. `awk -F'\r' '{print $1"A"}' file_list.txt`
4. ...

Widely accepted at last:

```
tr -d '\r' <file_list.txt | do_what_ever_want
```

Comment: The 2. solved my problem

Comment: @OHLÁLÁ And 1st didn't ? Try `sed 's/\r//;s/$/A/' file_list.txt`

Answer (score 3):

`sed` will do this quite handily

```
sed 's/$/ A/' file_list.txt
```

Comment: If you want to edit the existing file instead of printing the resulting test to `stdout` use the `-i` flag with `sed`

Comment: This gives the same result, the A is in a new line

Comment: Then check your file format. That's usually a symptom of dos vs. unix file formats.

Comment: I can reproduce with the followings:`printf '%s\r\n%s\r\n' foo bar | awk '{print $0"A"}' >test`. How can I overcome of this?